# My TCP Listener sends data and then closes. I don't know why?

Tags: c#, .net, callback

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace BLHClient
{
    class chCon
    {
        static TcpClient clientCon;
        static NetworkStream stream;
        public static bool currentlyConnected;

        static bool rDHasLoopedOnce = false;

        static string buffer = "";

        Thread retrieveData;

        string ip = "";
        int port = 0;

        public chCon(string ipAddress, int portNumber)
        {
            ip = ipAddress;
            port = portNumber;

            connectToConsole();
        }

        public void connectToConsole()//mitigates the connection
        {
            if (ip.Trim() == "")
                ip = "127.0.0.1";

            if (port == 0)
                port = 2647;

            try
            {
                clientCon = new TcpClient(ip, port);
                stream = clientCon.GetStream();

                //sendData("#101"); //first bit of data is sent on accepted client

                retrieveData = new Thread(receiveData_Stage1);
                retrieveData.Start();
            }

            catch (Exception e) // if the connection being naughty ;)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception caught:\n" + e);
            }

        }

        public void disconnectFromConsole()
        {
            try
            {
                if (clientCon.Connected || clientCon.Connected == null)
                {
                    retrieveData.Abort();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("#103");
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    stream.Close();
                    clientCon.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot disconnect from a connection that has not started.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error thrown during disconnection - UNKNOWN");
            }
        }

        public void sendData(string data)//sends data to the server
        {
            Byte[] dataConv = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            stream.Write(dataConv, 0, dataConv.Length);

        }

        public static void receiveData_Stage1() //builds a buffer through a loop
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Byte[] response = new Byte[256];
                    string responseData = String.Empty;

                    // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                    Int32 bytes = stream.Read(response, 0, response.Length);
                    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);

                    if (responseData.Trim() == "\0")
                        responseData = "";

                    if (responseData.Trim() != "")
                        buffer = buffer + responseData + "\n";

                    if (rDHasLoopedOnce == false)
                        rDHasLoopedOnce = true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        public string receiveData_Stage2() //requests the buffer through a return value string
        {
            string bufferTemp;
            bufferTemp = buffer;

            buffer = string.Empty;

            return bufferTemp;
        }

        public bool isConnected()
        {
            return clientCon.Connected;
        }

        public bool hasLoopedOnce()
        {
            return rDHasLoopedOnce;
        }
    }
    /*
    while (true)
        {
            if (Program.currentlyConnected == true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                buffer = Program.receiveData_Stage2();
                if (buffer != "")
                    richTxtBoxConsole.AppendText(buffer + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                guiConsoleWriteLine("Connection is not active.");
                break;
            }

        }
     */

}
```

This code above works, however for some reason whenever I call it and track it through debug, it seems to call connectToConsole() more than once. It's not as if I'm recursively calling it. What can I do?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should never have an empty catch all statement, except in very rare cases when you are 100% sure that you know what you are doing. Otherwise, when you program does not work, you won't know why, like in this case. Because you are suppressing not only information that might help you troubleshoot, but also you are suppressing any direct indication that you have a problem in the first place, and then you are at a loss because *something else* is not working for the reason you do not know about.